# Distribute the sum of both the 2 integer lists in 3 generated lists in such a way that unique elements considered from both lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

First of all forgive me for such a title.

**Problem:**

Consider 2 lists, namely `Linux` and `Windows` wherein elements correspond to task hours for any tester. Now generate 3 lists for 3 different testers.

**Constraint:**

Those 3 lists should have equal task hours and tester should not repeat the same task on both the platforms.

```
Linux = [2,3,4,4,3]
Windows = [2,3,4,4,3]
tester1 = []
tester2 = []
tester3 = []

for h, r in zip(Linux, Windows):
    if sum(tester1) <= sum(tester2):
        tester1.append(h)
        tester1.append(r)
    elif sum(tester2) <= sum(tester3):
        tester2.append(h)
        tester2.append(r)
    else:
        tester3.append(h)
        tester3.append(r)
print(
    'Task Distribution for 3 Testers:',
    '\nTester1:', tester1 ,
    'Total hours for Tester1:',
    sum(tester1),
    '\nTester2:',
    tester2 ,
    'Total hours for Tester2:',
    sum(tester2),
    '\nTester3:',
    tester3,
    'Total hours for Tester3:', 
    sum(tester3)
)
```

*I would expect output something this way:*
[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I wish to distribute the given task hours to 3 different testers nearly equally and same task should not be repeated on both the platforms by same tester.